# Square connect ID vs TRANSACTION_ID?

Tags: square-connect

When Square payment is successful there are two IDs returned:

```
   [id:protected] => 0cb1f61b-0f17-53b6-5048-58266ada510c
   [transaction_id:protected] => 8f753779-ae34-5d7f-5e53-376022545a37
```

1. assuming the "transaction_id" is what it says - what is "id" for then?
2. is there a better way to retrieve the transaction id (please see below)?

   **$result['transaction']->getId();**

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking at a tender or a refund? There are some objects that have their individual id's, and also display the transaction id that they are associated with.

You likely want to do something like

```
$result->getTransaction()->getId();
```

Comment: Thank you. At a tender. Btw - will I be able to get transaction by ID from Square Dashboard? I have spent some time fiddling with various controls there but was unable to locate "search by transaction ID". Googling proved the fact it is still not possible to get a transaction by ID. Is that still so? How can I quickly check a transaction to make sure it was successful form the dashboard?  Thanks once again!

Comment: It isn't very easy to go between the API and Dashboard. If you want to check if a transaction was successful, I'd recommend using the API and retrieving the transaction.

Comment: That's the main problem as we have our own backend with logged transactions. So if there is a concern  - our financial guys would like to be able to copy transaction ID from our backend to check it using Square dashboard. Pretty much the way it's done by Paypal
Please have a look:
http://a5w.org/up/uploads/mike/2017-10-04/1507081766_paypal_trans_id.jpg

Comment: If you look at the URLs you can probably find what you are looking for, but it isn't something we technically document.

Comment: woah! indeed - there is that very thing I have been looking for. Is there a chance that URL could be changed in the nearest future? Thanks for the tip!!!

Comment: Not the nearest, you should be  for now, but because it isn't documented, no gauretees.